# How to solve this error in updating?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for update and my problem is that i get this kind of error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" and i dont't know how to fix this..can somebody help me fix this?

**class.user.php**

```
public function update($user_id,$username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login SET username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE user_id=:user_id");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();

  return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;
}
}
```

**and here is the update.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';



    if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
    {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];

    if($crud->update($user_id,$username,$password,$province))
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!');</script>";
    }
}
    if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
    {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    extract($crud->getID($user_id)); 
}
?>

<div id="Survey-Update">
<form method='post'>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>Date Reported</td>
            <td>
                <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            </td>

            <td>Remarks</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="Remarks" type="text" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Remarks</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="Remarks" type="text" name="province" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $province; ?>">
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">
                    <span class="edit"></span>Update</button>
                        <a href="insert.php" onClick="self.close()"> &nbsp;  CANCEL</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `user_id=:user_id`??

Comment: @b0s3 what's wrong with that?

Comment: `4 != 3`. Check the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the number of `bindparams` is not the same as the number of `parameters`. You have 4 parameters, but you bind only 3.

You have:

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login SET username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
$stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
$stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
```

You should have something like:

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login SET username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
$stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
$stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
$stmt->bindparam(":user_id",$user_id);
```

You never bind the `user_id` parameter.

Comment: do i need to bind the user_id even if it is set to auto increment?

Comment: You need to bind it, because you use it in your SQL statement `WHERE user_id=:user_id` SIDE NOTE: What does the binding do? It tells `PHP` which variables to enter where in your SQL statement.